# Google AMP Guidelines Clarifications Needed

Tags: css, responsive-design, styles, amp-html

I have begun the process of creating an exact duplicate of one of my canonical websites -- it is a small site by modern standards of only about 6,500 pages -- which I hope will eventually be fully AMP-compliant by the time I am done.

I have read through a lot of the documentation on your website, and I find myself a bit confused regarding a few issues. Thus, I have some easy, straight-forward questions. Allow me to enumerate some of them for you.

1. The duplicate AMP-compliant version of my canonical website is located in a folder/directory that is at the top level of my regular canonical website. In other words, my AMP folder -- which will be self-contained, and hold all of my AMP-converted HTML files -- sits at the same level as the index.html file for the regular, canonical version of the same website. Is there a problem with doing this?

BTW, I host my own web server on an old iMac, and I really can't afford to be paying for yet another new domain, just to have an AMP version of my website. Thus this approach.

2. On the canonical version of my website, is the only AMP-related info that I really need in the head section of each HTML file, the `"<link rel="amphtml>"` link?

In other words, I really don't need the "viewport" meta tag, or the `"<html amp=>"`, etc., right? All of that is only for the actual AMP pages, correct? And, yes, I will have a link on my AMP pages back to the canonical pages as well. :)

3. In your Responsive Web Design Basics section, you state that using external stylesheets is prohibited, and that all CSS styles should be included in the head section of each individual HTML document. Obviously, this is going to bloat each HTML page even more, but I will do it, if that is the way that it needs to be done.

But here is what has me confused. In that same section of your website, you discuss CSS media queries, and provide clear examples of using ". While I do use a lot of inline CSS in my canonical website -- which I know I need to remove for AMP compliance -- I also have long used a number of CSS stylesheet documents located in a CSS folder at the top level of my canonical domain.

So are you saying that this is now prohibited, and that all of the CSS info in the stylesheets has to be added to the head of each file -- as per your "Disallowed Styles" section -- or do you mean something else by "external stylesheets", such as on another website?

4. In the "Disallowed Styles" section you also state that the "filter" style is "backlisted due to performance concerns." Are you referring to something like the following, because I use it a lot to add gradients to the top title and image portion of thousands of my pages:

`style="filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='# 34ddfc', endColorstr='#031578'); background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#34ddfc), to(#031578)); background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #34ddfc, #031578);"`

5. If I understand your documentation correctly, I cannot have the Facebook, Google+ and Twitter share buttons on any of my AMP pages, because they use inline scripts. Is this correct?
6. Based on what I have read regarding styling, are you suggesting that I should actually create different physical sizes of the same image, and then use the "srcset" element selector and "layout="responsive" to tell the page which image to display, depending on the device being used? I am still wrapping my head around exactly how to implement this properly.
7. Based on what I have read, and what I have done thus far to convert my canonical site to AMP, I already know in advance that I am breaking a number of AMP's basic rules. That being the case, why does your Mobile Friendly Test Tool give me the green light and say that my documents pass the test, and claim that the converted pages are mobile-friendly, while amproject.org display all kinds of AMP-related problems with my pages, which are more than likely correct? That is, they are valid errors, I believe.

As you can see by the above seven questions, while I already know that it is going to take a lot of time and hard work -- maybe weeks or months of effort on my part -- to get everything converted to AMP right and properly, I am committed to doing this myself, because I can't possibly afford to pay someone else to do it for me. I am old and retired. So, I hope that you are able to clearly answer the above seven questions, because I am very eager to plow into this more than I have already, as soon as possible. I have many mobile-device-using friends. Thankfully, I use a great text editor which makes global search and replace code a lot easier, and less time-consuming, than if I had to do everything manually. Yes, I will be forced, nevertheless to do a lot of manual stuff too, but it could be worse. :)

Thanks in advance for any assistance you can provide. No doubt, I will have more questions as I proceed with this project.

Comment: I apologize. In question 3 I forgot to use back ticks. That one sentence was actually supposed to say "In that same section of your website, you discuss CSS media queries, and provide clear examples of using `"<link rel="stylesheet"`."

Answer (score 0):

1. No need to worry: it doesn't make a difference with respect to AMP where you store the files that make up your website
2. That's correct. Your canonical page just needs the `<link rel="canonical" href="...">` tag. It's recommended that your canonical and AMP documents be as similar as possible in terms of content, as well.
3. That's right — valid AMP requires that CSS be in the `<head>` of the document
4. All uses of the CSS filter style are prohibited in valid AMP, including the usage you describe
5. Any buttons with inline, third-party scripts are prohibited, but you may be able to use [amp-social-share](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-social-share/) to support the functionality you're looking for.
6. You can see a nice example of how `srcset` works at [AMP by Example](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-img/)
7. The Mobile Friendly Test Tool and the AMP validator test for unrelated things. If you just want to make valid AMP pages, the AMP validator should give you the feedback you need.